# Send CSV file to jersey rest API in java using php CURL request?

Tags: java, php, rest, curl, jersey-2.0

I would like to call Rest API which is in Jersey java. The code of rest API is :

```
@POST
@Path("/csv1")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile1(@FormDataParam("type") int type ,@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
{
}
```

I want to call it from CURL request using ajax in php. How can I do so?

Comment: You want to consume that API using curl in PHP and want it to be AJAX, so you should generate the XMLHttpRequest JavaScript code to upload the file to that API.

Comment: If you're not interested in the Async, JavaScript and XML parts of AJAX and would rather just send a file to that API, just say so and someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the AJAX requirement, this is how you send a file with cURL from PHP to the /csv1 API at example.com.

```
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/csv1');

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = curl_file_create('localfilename.csv','text/csv','sentfilename.csv');

// Assign POST data
$data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// Execute the handle
curl_exec($ch);
```

Just be aware: Sending cURL requests in PHP is blocking and not asynchronous as you stated in your requirement.